# how to disable psplash screen in yocto

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, yocto, splash-screen

i am struggeling since couple of hours to disable the psplash image in yocto to produce an image for raspberry pi.

I created a bbappend file to remove the splash files, but only the splash.sh was removed correctly, the result like psplash_write is still kept at /usr/bin

The yocto docu states to disable it we need to pass psplash = false to the kernel command line, but how can i pass it .

your help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [**Raspberry pi StackExchange**](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

To disable psplash, reliably, you have to remove "splash" (not psplash) from IMAGE_FEATURES. I was able to remove the psplash on Raspberry Pi 4 and Xavier NX by adding below to my local.conf

```
IMAGE_FEATURES_remove += "splash"
```

More reading on this here https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-features-image

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your image and add:

```
IMAGE_FEATURE_remove = "psplash"
```

It will remove `psplash` from the default `IMAGE_FEATURE` variable.

Comment: i tried it but it does not work. A file called usingpoky.xml states at line 1018 that we need to pass psplash=false to the kernel. but i don't know how. It should be using the bootargs with uboot but it is unclear how.

Comment: by the way IMAGE_FEATURE should not be used in local.conf, but EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURE instead as per documentation

Comment: It is called IMAGE_FEATURES

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for raspberrypi, in case somebody searches in future

inside meta-raspberrypi/recipes-bsp/rpi-u-boot-scr/files/boot.cmd
there is one line to be added before the last line as follows:

> setenv bootargs psplash=false

the full file is as follows:

> fdt addr ${fdt_addr} && fdt get value bootargs /chosen bootargs
>
> fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} uImage
>
> setenv bootargs psplash=false
>
> bootm ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}

-> there is no need to add any psplash recipies, but there is a drawback, i get in the log  **umount: can't unmount /mnt/.psplash: Invalid argument**, which is another problem from the psplash.sh script.

This error comes from the following patch :[enter link description here](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/47017/)

this error comes from existance of /usr/bin/psplash-write by removing it manually, the error vanish, but removing it with a recipe edit was not sucessful

Comment: Setting psplash=false only applies if using sysvinit, if using systemd it will not do the trick and instead you should remove `splash` from `IMAGE_FEATURES`.